# Android adding Json objects into an Array

Tags: android, json

What I'm trying to do is create a JSONObject that contains an Array of other JSONObjects that are organized by a String? for example i want to create a JSONObject that contains an array of objects that contain fixtures that are also organized by match date

to give you a visual reference of what i am trying to acheive

```
JSONObject (JSONArray("Object 10/10/12" {(fixtures content)(fixtures content)}")
                     ("Object 11/10/12" {(fixtures content)(fixtures content)}"))
```

heres what i have tried so far but just can't get it to work

```
        String matchDate1 = null;
        JSONArray datesArray = null;
        JSONObject fixturesInfo = null;
        JSONArray fixturesInfoArray = null;
        String matchDateTemp = null;

        for(int f = 0; f < fixturesArray.length(); f++){

            JSONObject matchDateDict = fixturesArray.getJSONObject(f);
            matchDate1 = matchDateDict.getString("matchdate");
            JSONArray fixturesInfoDict = fixturesInfo.getJSONArray(matchDate1);

           if(fixturesInfoDict == null){
               tempArray = null;
           } else {
               tempArray = fixturesInfoDict;
           }

           if(matchDateTemp != matchDate1){
              fixturesInfoArray.put(matchDate1);
           }

          matchDateTemp = matchDate1;

          tempArray.put(fixturesArray.getJSONObject(f));
          fixturesInfo.put(matchDate1, tempArray);

        }




            Log.v("MyFix", "fixturesInfo = " + fixturesInfo);

        }catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

heres the json feed

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "error": null,
    "data": {
        "fixtures": [{
            "kickoff": "15:00:00",
            "matchdate": "2012-07-14",
            "homescore": null,
            "awayscore": null,
            "attendance": null,
            "homepens": null,
            "awaypens": null,
            "division_id": "5059",
            "division": "Testing 1",
            "comp": "LGE",
            "location": null,
            "fixture_note": null,
            "hometeam_id": "64930",
            "hometeam": "Team 1",
            "awayteam_id": "64933",
            "awayteam": "Team 4"
        }, {
            "kickoff": "15:00:00",
            "matchdate": "2012-07-14",
            "homescore": null,
            "awayscore": null,
            "attendance": null,
            "homepens": null,
            "awaypens": null,
            "division_id": "5059",
            "division": "Testing 1",
            "comp": "LGE",
            "location": null,
            "fixture_note": null,
            "hometeam_id": "64935",
            "hometeam": "Team 6",
            "awayteam_id": "64937",
            "awayteam": "Team 8"
        }, {
            "kickoff": "15:00:00",
            "matchdate": "2012-07-28",
            "homescore": null,
            "awayscore": null,
            "attendance": null,
            "homepens": null,
            "awaypens": null,
            "division_id": "5059",
            "division": "Testing 1",
            "comp": "LGE",
            "location": null,
            "fixture_note": null,
            "hometeam_id": "64930",
            "hometeam": "Team 1",
            "awayteam_id": "64931",
            "awayteam": "Team 2"
        }, {
            "kickoff": "15:00:00",
            "matchdate": "2012-07-28",
            "homescore": null,
            "awayscore": null,
            "attendance": null,
            "homepens": null,
            "awaypens": null,
            "division_id": "5059",
            "division": "Testing 1",
            "comp": "LGE",
            "location": null,
            "fixture_note": null,
            "hometeam_id": "64930",
            "hometeam": "Team 1",
            "awayteam_id": "64931",
            "awayteam": "Team 2"
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From what you say, you seem like trying to build a `JSONArray` out of some `JSONObjects`. This might help:

```
public void writeJSON() {
    JSONObject user = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject user2;
    user2 = new JSONObject();
    try {
        user.put("dish_id", "1");
        user.put("dish_custom", "2");
        user.put("quantity", "2");
        user.put("shared", "2");

        user2.put("dish_id", "2");
        user2.put("dish_custom", "2");
        user2.put("quantity", "4");
        user2.put("shared", "3");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONArray notebookUsers = new JSONArray();
    notebookUsers.put(user);
    notebookUsers.put(user2);
    System.out.println("the JSON ARRAY is"+notebookUsers);
```

Here 2 json objects are added to 1 JSONArray.

The output of the `System.out.println` will look something like this:

```
the JSON ARRAY is[{"shared":"2","dish_custom":"2","dish_id":"1","quantity":"2"},{"shared":"3","dish_custom":"2","dish_id":"2","quantity":"4"}]
```

And the string comparison you are using is not right.

```
if(matchDateTemp != matchDate1)
```

u cannot compare strings like that. u can use something like:

```
if(!(matchDateTemp.equals(matchDate1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to parse JSON is to use [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list). What you have to do is

- Download GSON jar and add to your build path
- Now create classes that represent your JSON data structure
- Parse the data in just one line. GSON will do that for you

parsing in just one line

```
String json = "{\"code\":200,\"error\":null,\"data\":{\"fixtures\":[{\"kickoff\":\"15:00:00\",\"matchdate\":\"2012-07-14\",\"homescore\":null,\"awayscore\":null,\"attendance\":null,\"homepens\":null,\"awaypens\":null,\"division_id\":\"5059\",\"division\":\"Testing 1\",\"comp\":\"LGE\",\"location\":null,\"fixture_note\":null,\"hometeam_id\":\"64930\",\"hometeam\":\"Team 1\",\"awayteam_id\":\"64933\",\"awayteam\":\"Team 4\"},{\"kickoff\":\"15:00:00\",\"matchdate\":\"2012-07-14\",\"homescore\":null,\"awayscore\":null,\"attendance\":null,\"homepens\":null,\"awaypens\":null,\"division_id\":\"5059\",\"division\":\"Testing 1\",\"comp\":\"LGE\",\"location\":null,\"fixture_note\":null,\"hometeam_id\":\"64935\",\"hometeam\":\"Team 6\",\"awayteam_id\":\"64937\",\"awayteam\":\"Team 8\"},{\"kickoff\":\"15:00:00\",\"matchdate\":\"2012-07-28\",\"homescore\":null,\"awayscore\":null,\"attendance\":null,\"homepens\":null,\"awaypens\":null,\"division_id\":\"5059\",\"division\":\"Testing 1\",\"comp\":\"LGE\",\"location\":null,\"fixture_note\":null,\"hometeam_id\":\"64930\",\"hometeam\":\"Team 1\",\"awayteam_id\":\"64931\",\"awayteam\":\"Team 2\"},{\"kickoff\":\"15:00:00\",\"matchdate\":\"2012-07-28\",\"homescore\":null,\"awayscore\":null,\"attendance\":null,\"homepens\":null,\"awaypens\":null,\"division_id\":\"5059\",\"division\":\"Testing 1\",\"comp\":\"LGE\",\"location\":null,\"fixture_note\":null,\"hometeam_id\":\"64930\",\"hometeam\":\"Team 1\",\"awayteam_id\":\"64931\",\"awayteam\":\"Team 2\"}]}}";

MatchDetails matchDetails=new Gson().fromJson(json,MatchDetails.class);
System.out.println(matchDetails);
```

- Now the `MatchDetails` class has all the `Fixture`  `Lists` you need
- access the fixture array via `matchDetails.getData().getFixtures();`

the `MatchDetails` class

```
public class MatchDetails {

    //"code":200,"error":null

    private String code;
    private String error;
    private Fixtures data;
    /**
     * Gets the code.
     * 
     * @return <tt> the code.</tt>
     */
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    /**
     * Sets the code.
     *
     * @param code <tt> the code to set.</tt>
     */
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    /**
     * Gets the error.
     * 
     * @return <tt> the error.</tt>
     */
    public String getError() {
        return error;
    }
    /**
     * Sets the error.
     *
     * @param error <tt> the error to set.</tt>
     */
    public void setError(String error) {
        this.error = error;
    }
    /**
     * Gets the data.
     * 
     * @return <tt> the data.</tt>
     */
    public Fixtures getData() {
        return data;
    }
    /**
     * Sets the data.
     *
     * @param data <tt> the data to set.</tt>
     */
    public void setData(Fixtures data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MatchDetails [code=" + code + ", error=" + error + ", data="
                + data + "]";
    }


}
```

**EDIT**
edited `Fixtures` class with `sortFixtures` function. Use it as below

```
String json = "{\"code\":200,\"error\":null,\"data\":{\"fixtures\":[{\"kickoff\":\"15:00:00\",\"matchdate\":\"2012-05-14\",\"homescore\":null,\"awayscore\":null,\"attendance\":null,\"homepens\":null,\"awaypens\":null,\"division_id\":\"5059\",\"division\":\"Testing 1\",\"comp\":\"LGE\",\"location\":null,\"fixture_note\":null,\"hometeam_id\":\"64930\",\"hometeam\":\"Team 1\",\"awayteam_id\":\"64933\",\"awayteam\":\"Team 4\"},{\"kickoff\":\"15:00:00\",\"matchdate\":\"2012-07-14\",\"homescore\":null,\"awayscore\":null,\"attendance\":null,\"homepens\":null,\"awaypens\":null,\"division_id\":\"5059\",\"division\":\"Testing 1\",\"comp\":\"LGE\",\"location\":null,\"fixture_note\":null,\"hometeam_id\":\"64935\",\"hometeam\":\"Team 6\",\"awayteam_id\":\"64937\",\"awayteam\":\"Team 8\"},{\"kickoff\":\"15:00:00\",\"matchdate\":\"2012-12-28\",\"homescore\":null,\"awayscore\":null,\"attendance\":null,\"homepens\":null,\"awaypens\":null,\"division_id\":\"5059\",\"division\":\"Testing 1\",\"comp\":\"LGE\",\"location\":null,\"fixture_note\":null,\"hometeam_id\":\"64930\",\"hometeam\":\"Team 1\",\"awayteam_id\":\"64931\",\"awayteam\":\"Team 2\"},{\"kickoff\":\"15:00:00\",\"matchdate\":\"2012-01-28\",\"homescore\":null,\"awayscore\":null,\"attendance\":null,\"homepens\":null,\"awaypens\":null,\"division_id\":\"5059\",\"division\":\"Testing 1\",\"comp\":\"LGE\",\"location\":null,\"fixture_note\":null,\"hometeam_id\":\"64930\",\"hometeam\":\"Team 1\",\"awayteam_id\":\"64931\",\"awayteam\":\"Team 2\"}]}}";

MatchDetails matchDetails=new Gson().fromJson(json,MatchDetails.class);
System.out.println(matchDetails);

System.out.println("Unsorted");

Fixtures fixturesObj = matchDetails.getData(); 
List<Fixture> fixtures = fixturesObj.getFixtures();
for (Fixture fixture : fixtures) {
    System.out.println(fixture);
}

System.out.println("Sorted");

fixtures = fixturesObj.sortFixtures();
for (Fixture fixture : fixtures) {
    System.out.println(fixture);
}
```

The `Fixtures` class

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * <br>
 * <div style="width:600px;text-align:justify;">
 *
 * TODO: Class comment.
 *
 * </div>
 * <br>
 * @author Sunil Kumar E
 *
 */
public class Fixtures {

    private List<Fixture> fixtures;

    /**
     * Gets the fixtures.
     * 
     * @return <tt> the fixtures.</tt>
     */
    public List<Fixture> getFixtures() {
        return fixtures;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the fixtures.
     *
     * @param fixtures <tt> the fixtures to set.</tt>
     */
    public void setFixtures(List<Fixture> fixtures) {
        this.fixtures = fixtures;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Fixtures [fixtures=" + fixtures + "]";
    }


    public List<Fixture> sortFixtures()
    {
        Collections.sort(getFixtures(), new Comparator<Fixture>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Fixture o1, Fixture o2) {
                SimpleDateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

                Date date1 = null;
                Date date2 = null;

                try {
                    date1 = df1 .parse(o1.getMatchdate());
                    date2 = df1 .parse(o2.getMatchdate());
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(date1==null || date2==null) return 0;

                if (date1.after(date2))
                    return 1;
                else if(date1.before(date2)) 
                    return -1;
                return 0;
            }
        });

        return getFixtures();
    }
}
```

the `Fixture` class

```
public class Fixture {
//"kickoff":"15:00:00","matchdate":"2012-07-14","homescore":null,
//  "awayscore":null,"attendance":null,"homepens":null,"awaypens":null,
//  "division_id":"5059","division":"Testing 1","comp":"LGE","location":null,
//  "fixture_note":null,"hometeam_id":"64930","hometeam":"Team 1",
//  "awayteam_id":"64933","awayteam":"Team 4"

    private String kickoff;
    private String matchdate;
    private String homescore;
    private String awayscore;
    private String attendance;
    private String homepens;
    private String awaypens;
    private String division_id;
    private String division;
    private String comp;
    private String location;
    private String fixture_note;
    private String hometeam_id;
    private String hometeam;
    private String awayteam_id;
    private String awayteam;
    /**
     * Gets the kickoff.
     * 
     * @return <tt> the kickoff.</tt>
     */
    public String getKickoff() {
        return kickoff;
    }
    /**
     * Sets the kickoff.
     *
     * @param kickoff <tt> the kickoff to set.</tt>
     */
    public void setKickoff(String kickoff) {
        this.kickoff = kickoff;
    }
    /**
     * Gets the matchdate.
     * 
     * @return <tt> the matchdate.</tt>
     */
    public String getMatchdate() {
        return matchdate;
    }
    /**
     * Sets the matchdate.
     *
     * @param matchdate <tt> the matchdate to set.</tt>
     */
    public void setMatchdate(String matchdate) {
        this.matchdate = matchdate;
    }
    /**
     * Gets the homescore.
     * 
     * @return <tt> the homescore.</tt>
     */
    public String getHomescore() {
        return homescore;
    }
    /**
     * Sets the homescore.
     *
     * @param homescore <tt> the homescore to set.</tt>
     */
    public void setHomescore(String homescore) {
        this.homescore = homescore;
    }
    /**
     * Gets the awayscore.
     * 
     * @return <tt> the awayscore.</tt>
     */
    public String getAwayscore() {
        return awayscore;
    }
    /**
     * Sets the awayscore.
     *
     * @param awayscore <tt> the awayscore to set.</tt>
     */
    public void setAwayscore(String awayscore) {
        this.awayscore = awayscore;
    }
    /**
     * Gets the attendance.
     * 
     * @return <tt> the attendance.</tt>
     */
    public String getAttendance() {
        return attendance;
    }
    /**
     * Sets the attendance.
     *
     * @param attendance <tt> the attendance to set.</tt>
     */
    public void setAttendance(String attendance) {
        this.attendance = attendance;
    }
    /**
     * Gets the homepens.
     * 
     * @return <tt> the homepens.</tt>
     */
    public String getHomepens() {
        return homepens;
    }
    /**
     * Sets the homepens.
     *
     * @param homepens <tt> the homepens to set.</tt>
     */
    public void setHomepens(String homepens) {
        this.homepens = homepens;
    }
    /**
     * Gets the awaypens.
     * 
     * @return <tt> the awaypens.</tt>
     */
    public String getAwaypens() {
        return awaypens;
    }
    /**
     * Sets the awaypens.
     *
     * @param awaypens <tt> the awaypens to set.</tt>
     */
    public void setAwaypens(String awaypens) {
        this.awaypens = awaypens;
    }
    /**
     * Gets the division_id.
     * 
     * @return <tt> the division_id.</tt>
     */
    public String getDivision_id() {
        return division_id;
    }
    /**
     * Sets the division_id.
     *
     * @param division_id <tt> the division_id to set.</tt>
     */
    public void setDivision_id(String division_id) {
        this.division_id = division_id;
    }
    /**
     * Gets the division.
     * 
     * @return <tt> the division.</tt>
     */
    public String getDivision() {
        return division;
    }
    /**
     * Sets the division.
     *
     * @param division <tt> the division to set.</tt>
     */
    public void setDivision(String division) {
        this.division = division;
    }
    /**
     * Gets the comp.
     * 
     * @return <tt> the comp.</tt>
     */
    public String getComp() {
        return comp;
    }
    /**
     * Sets the comp.
     *
     * @param comp <tt> the comp to set.</tt>
     */
    public void setComp(String comp) {
        this.comp = comp;
    }
    /**
     * Gets the location.
     * 
     * @return <tt> the location.</tt>
     */
    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
    /**
     * Sets the location.
     *
     * @param location <tt> the location to set.</tt>
     */
    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
    /**
     * Gets the fixture_note.
     * 
     * @return <tt> the fixture_note.</tt>
     */
    public String getFixture_note() {
        return fixture_note;
    }
    /**
     * Sets the fixture_note.
     *
     * @param fixture_note <tt> the fixture_note to set.</tt>
     */
    public void setFixture_note(String fixture_note) {
        this.fixture_note = fixture_note;
    }
    /**
     * Gets the hometeam_id.
     * 
     * @return <tt> the hometeam_id.</tt>
     */
    public String getHometeam_id() {
        return hometeam_id;
    }
    /**
     * Sets the hometeam_id.
     *
     * @param hometeam_id <tt> the hometeam_id to set.</tt>
     */
    public void setHometeam_id(String hometeam_id) {
        this.hometeam_id = hometeam_id;
    }
    /**
     * Gets the hometeam.
     * 
     * @return <tt> the hometeam.</tt>
     */
    public String getHometeam() {
        return hometeam;
    }
    /**
     * Sets the hometeam.
     *
     * @param hometeam <tt> the hometeam to set.</tt>
     */
    public void setHometeam(String hometeam) {
        this.hometeam = hometeam;
    }
    /**
     * Gets the awayteam_id.
     * 
     * @return <tt> the awayteam_id.</tt>
     */
    public String getAwayteam_id() {
        return awayteam_id;
    }
    /**
     * Sets the awayteam_id.
     *
     * @param awayteam_id <tt> the awayteam_id to set.</tt>
     */
    public void setAwayteam_id(String awayteam_id) {
        this.awayteam_id = awayteam_id;
    }
    /**
     * Gets the awayteam.
     * 
     * @return <tt> the awayteam.</tt>
     */
    public String getAwayteam() {
        return awayteam;
    }
    /**
     * Sets the awayteam.
     *
     * @param awayteam <tt> the awayteam to set.</tt>
     */
    public void setAwayteam(String awayteam) {
        this.awayteam = awayteam;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Fixture [kickoff=" + kickoff + ", matchdate=" + matchdate
                + ", homescore=" + homescore + ", awayscore=" + awayscore
                + ", attendance=" + attendance + ", homepens=" + homepens
                + ", awaypens=" + awaypens + ", division_id=" + division_id
                + ", division=" + division + ", comp=" + comp + ", location="
                + location + ", fixture_note=" + fixture_note
                + ", hometeam_id=" + hometeam_id + ", hometeam=" + hometeam
                + ", awayteam_id=" + awayteam_id + ", awayteam=" + awayteam
                + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see the part in your code where it sorts the fixtures by date.

Comment: you have all the Fixtures stored in List now and can just apply any date sorting logic to sort the fixtures

Comment: @Squonk added a function to sort Fixtures

Comment: @Luke were you able to test this ?