# android JSON for loop null pointer exception

Tags: android, json

hi i'm trying to create an JSONObject that contains an array of dates that contain fixtures at the i'm currently getting a null pointer exception at this line `if(fixturesDict.length() == 0){` does anyone know why?

heres my code

```
public void FillData() throws JSONException{    

      ListView list = getListView();
        list.scrollTo(0, 0);
        list.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);

           list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

           LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );





       fixturesView = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.fixturescell,
                 null);


       //Log.v("MyFix", "fixturesArray = " + fixturesArray);
       if(fixturesArray.length() < 1){

             TextView emptytext = (TextView) fixturesView.findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
             emptytext.setText("No Upcoming Fixtures Available");

       }else{
        try{   




            for(int t = 0; t < fixturesArray.length(); t++){
               JSONObject matchDateDict = fixturesArray.getJSONObject(t);
                matchDate = matchDateDict.getString("matchdate");

               if(matchDatesHeadersArray.length() != 0){
                   int lm = t - 1;
                   JSONObject lastDateDict = fixturesArray.getJSONObject(lm);
                   String lastMatchDate = lastDateDict.getString("matchdate");

                   if(matchDate.equals(lastMatchDate)){
                   } else {
                       matchDatesHeadersArray.put(matchDate);
                   }
               } else {
                   matchDatesHeadersArray.put(matchDate);     
               }               
            }

            JSONObject fixturesDict = new JSONObject();
            JSONArray tempArray = new JSONArray();
            JSONArray newTempArray = new JSONArray();
            JSONObject tempDict = null;

            for(int f = 0; f < fixturesArray.length(); f++){
                String matchDateHeaderString = matchDatesHeadersArray.getString(f);
                tempDict = fixturesArray.getJSONObject(f);
                String currentMatchDate = tempDict.getString("matchdate");
                Log.v("myFix", "matchDateHeaderString = " + matchDateHeaderString + "currentMatchDate = " + currentMatchDate);



*if(fixturesDict.length() == 0){*


                    tempArray = null;
                } else {
                    tempArray = fixturesDict.getJSONArray(currentMatchDate);
                }

                if(!currentMatchDate.equals(matchDateHeaderString)){
                    // ADD TEXT INTO ARRAY FOR HEADER TITLES
                }

                newTempArray.put(tempDict);
                fixturesDict.put(matchDateHeaderString, newTempArray);
                Log.v("myFix", "SEMI fixturesDict = " + fixturesDict);

            }

            Log.v("myFix", "FULL fixturesDict = " + fixturesDict);



        }catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

heres the error i'm getting

```
07-18 11:01:48.974: E/AndroidRuntime(26155): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-18 11:01:48.974: E/AndroidRuntime(26155):at MIFixtures.FillData(MIFixtures.java:455)
07-18 11:01:48.974: E/AndroidRuntime(26155):    at .MIFixtures$PostTask.onPostExecute(MIFixtures.java:390)
07-18 11:01:48.974: E/AndroidRuntime(26155):    at e.MIFixtures$PostTask.onPostExecute(MIFixtures.java:1)
07-18 11:01:48.974: E/AndroidRuntime(26155):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
07-18 11:01:48.974: E/AndroidRuntime(26155):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
07-18 11:01:48.974: E/AndroidRuntime(26155):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
07-18 11:01:48.974: E/AndroidRuntime(26155):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-18 11:01:48.974: E/AndroidRuntime(26155):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
07-18 11:01:48.974: E/AndroidRuntime(26155):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4263)
07-18 11:01:48.974: E/AndroidRuntime(26155):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 11:01:48.974: E/AndroidRuntime(26155):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-18 11:01:48.974: E/AndroidRuntime(26155):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-18 11:01:48.974: E/AndroidRuntime(26155):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-18 11:01:48.974: E/AndroidRuntime(26155):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

heres my json feed

```
{
    "code":200,
    "error":null,
    "data":{
        "fixtures":[
            {
                "kickoff":"15:00:00",
                "matchdate":"2012-07-28",
                "homescore":null,
                "awayscore":null,
                "attendance":null,
                "homepens":null,
                "awaypens":null,
                "division_id":"5059",
                "division":"Testing 1",
                "comp":"LGE",
                "location":null,
                "fixture_note":null,
                "hometeam_id":"64930",
                "hometeam":"Team 1",
                "awayteam_id":"64931",
                "awayteam":"Team 2"
            }, {
                "kickoff":"15:00:00",
                "matchdate":"2012-07-28",
                "homescore":null,
                "awayscore":null,
                "attendance":null,
                "homepens":null,
                "awaypens":null,
                "division_id":"5059",
                "division":"Testing 1",
                "comp":"LGE",
                "location":null,
```

Comment: For better help, please indent/reformat your code and tell us where exactly the exception occurs.

Comment: as logcat says you are getting NPE in `onPostExecute(MIFixtures.java:390)` post  your code

Comment: heyy luke... why are you repeating the same question ? is this a duplicate of this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11449803/android-adding-json-objects-into-an-array ?

Comment: it's not a repeat question its the same subject but a different question. plus my code is different from the last question

Comment: I doubt you are using `fixturesDict` in if condition in that loop instead you need to use `tempDict` object.

Comment: i haven't got it working yet but when i do i always go through and accept answers i thought helped at the moment i'm trying this route if i can't get this route working ill try your way.

Comment: @sunil also sorry for not replying i didnt notice the comment at the bottom so apologies

Comment: @LukeBatley Ok... no issues. do you face any issues with my code sample ? It is working perfectly fine and your issues will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Your `fixturesArray` haven't been created when you call `(fixturesArray.length() < 1)`

I suggest to check that variable  `fixturesArray` and make sure it has been initialized when u call

Answer (score 0):

Hello Refer below code

JSON String

```
{
"result": "success",
"countryCodeList":
[
  {"countryCode":"00","countryName":"World Wide"},
  {"countryCode":"kr","countryName":"Korea"}
] 
}
```

Here below I am fetching country details

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonstring);
JSONArray nameArray = json.names();
JSONArray valArray = json.toJSONArray(nameArray);

JSONArray valArray1 = valArray.getJSONArray(1);

valArray1.toString().replace("[", "");
valArray1.toString().replace("]", "");

int len = valArray1.length();

for (int i = 0; i < valArray1.length(); i++) {

 Country country = new Country();
 JSONObject arr = valArray1.getJSONObject(i);
 country.setCountryCode(arr.getString("countryCode"));                        
 country.setCountryName(arr.getString("countryName"));
 arrCountries.add(country);
}
```